# Google map goes blank when triggering click event outside

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I have created a google map using V3 js API, and inside the map I am showing multiple markers. When I am clicking on a markers it does an ajax call and shows the result in the infowindow. I have added an external link outside the map, clicking on which it will display the corresponding marker result in side the map. I have used the below code to do the functionality..

```
$('#marker_link').click(function () {
    var longitude = $(this).find("#longitude").val();
    var latitude = $(this).find("#latitude").val();
    var index = $(this).find("#index").val();

    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[index], "click", {
        latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)
    });
});
```

This code is pulling the marker data correctly and showing in a window. But at that time the map goes blank. How can we fix it. How can we keep the map along with the store result.

Here gmarkers[ ] is a global array where I am keeping all the markers that are created during the map is rendered.

The below code I have used while showing markers in the map for the first time.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    map: map,
                                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(pLat, pLong),
                                });
                                gmarkers.push(marker);

                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {


                                    var dataString = 'store_id=' + {{ store.store_id }}
                                    $.ajax({  
                                        type: "GET",  
                                        url: GET_STORE_DATA,  
                                        data: dataString, 
                                        success: function(res) { 
                                            if(res != '') {
                                                var contentString = res;
                                                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString });

                                                infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                                                infoWindow.open(map);
                                                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                                                    infoWindow.close();
                                                });
                                            } else {
                                                alert('No data found')
                                            }
                                        }  
                                    });
                                });
```

Comment: Does it work better if you use numbers rather than strings as latitude and longitude?  (parseFloat will convert a string to a number)

Comment: No its still the same. I have checked after using parseFloat(). Basically the marker infowindow is coming, but it is showing some outside of the map location.